# Page generation based on XML files (PHP, Jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xml

So I have XML data that I need to take and use in my PHP page, as search results. 
Problem - the XML is structured horribly (one "index" file with links that lead to other XML files) and the size of the whole thing is huuuge (from 1000 to 20+K XML files, 10 and more MBs in total).
There are lots of different tools I researched into: XMLreader, XML Parser and a bit of JQuery. But I'm not sure which one will be better for that task. 
What, I think would be the best way of solving it is a facebook-style "press to load more" kind of page that loads itself, loads the "index" XML (maybe in a hidden input field or a div so it can be read by JQuery), then starts actively reading XML files that are listed in the index and generate the results dynamically on the page. And I do need all the data in some sort of memory, since I will have to do analytics on it as well. 
Question: Which is better to use for it and any techniques I'd benefit from? Or am I looking at it from a wrong side completely?
I tried strait PHP reading using XMLreader and parser, as well as SimpleXMLElement + for=loop, but once I put a second read (from the "Index") into the equation the page just breaks from too big of loading times, and that's with 30MB/s internet. I don't have much experience with JQuery, so that's why I'm asking for advice.
P.S. I'm taking XML from http://www.clinicaltrials.gov
 
Example of a *smaller* "Index": http://www.clinicaltrials.gov/search?term=attack&count=1856&displayxml=true
If you add "?displayxml=true" to each of the "url"s there it will be an XML file that I need to read.

Comment: in your url example, there are `1856` results. you want to paginate them in a table? whats the end goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is:

Since the site provides some helpful query strings like `&count=`, take this advantage.

This means you really don't need to process and query tens of thousands of rows.

So normally, you just query the external site like this:

```
http://www.clinicaltrials.gov/search?term=heart%20attack&count=10&displayxml=true&pg=1
```

So just limit every request. Example: `10` at a time.

Then start building the server side.

The client site is up to you to decide, this is just personal preference but I would use `DataTables` in this example.

The code below just recreates the same structure in the sample url above:

```
$search_term = 'attack';
$count = 10;
$query = http_build_query(array(
    'term' => $search_term,
    'count' => $count,
    'displayxml' => 'true',
    'pg' => $draw,
));
$main_url = 'http://www.clinicaltrials.gov/search?' . $query;
```

After building the correct URL, just request the XML needed. An then ultimately, after you have gathered all the data you need (the chunked data). Present it on the client-side.

Full example: Also [**`Sample Fiddle`**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yh1PTY)

`index.php`

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $draw = isset($_POST['draw']) ? $_POST['draw'] : 1;
    $search_term = 'attack';
    $count = 10;
    $query = http_build_query(array(
        'term' => $search_term,
        'count' => $count,
        'displayxml' => 'true',
        'pg' => $draw,
    ));
    $main_url = 'http://www.clinicaltrials.gov/search?' . $query;
    $contents = file_get_contents($main_url);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($contents);
    $total_results = (string) $xml->attributes()['count'];
    $data = array();

    $data['draw'] = $draw;
    $data['recordsTotal'] = $total_results;
    $data['recordsFiltered'] = $total_results;
    foreach($xml->clinical_study as $entry) {
        $data['data'][] = json_decode(json_encode($entry), true);

    }

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<table border="1" class="display dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Nct ID</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Condition Summary</th>
            <th>Last Changed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Nct ID</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Condition Summary</th>
            <th>Last Changed</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.display').dataTable({
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'ajax': {
            'url': document.URL,
            'type': 'POST',
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "order" },
            { "data": "score" },
            { "data": "nct_id" },
            { "data": "url" },
            { "data": "title" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "condition_summary" },
            { "data": "last_changed" },
        ],
        bFilter: false, bInfo: false, bSort: false,
    });

});
</script>
```

So the basic idea here really is that you really don't need to request that thousand rows immediately. You can just call them in chunks instead.

Comment: Really cool method, but, again, not exactly what I'm looking for. 
I'm looking for a dynamic reading of data - "use search -> get a record -> process the record -> get to the next one -> process the records -> ... -> finish processing the records" and all of that without the  reloading the page.

Comment: @BlueLight of course there is an optional search on datatables as well, i just disabled it on its initialization, or you can just hook it up yourself, just like what i wrote on the notes, you can just paginate it thru the query string

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL) to take the clinicaltrials.gov XML and convert it into a sane XML format, including HTML. XSL is a language for transforming XML.

PHP even has a built in XSL processor: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php

On a side note, I use XSL to convert DocBook XML files (a semantic markup language) into Twitter Bootstrap HTML.

For example, using the example you've provided (http://www.clinicaltrials.gov/search?term=attack&count=1856&displayxml=true), if you wanted to display the titles of all of the clinical studies as a list, the following XSL stylesheet would do the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="search_results">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="clinical_study">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="title"/></li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSL stylesheet enters the source XML document at the root of the document. It then traverses the tree. Anytime that it finds an element which matches a defined template, it executes that template. Pretty cool stuff! It takes a while to orient yourself into the XSL paradigm of programming, but it is quite powerful once you get the hang of it.

Note that I just wrote that as a toy example off the top of my head. I'm not sure if that will actually execute properly.

**Edit 1:**

(OP asks about performing analysis, e.g. counting all elements of a specific type)

Looking at your example XML results, it looks like the only way to determine if a trial is in Phase 3 is to check the text of the `<title>` element. This is still easily within the capabilities of XSL (with some help from XPath).

```
<xsl:variable name="countPhase3">
   <xsl:value-of select="count(//title[text() = 'Phase 3' | text() = 'Phase III']"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

I'll warn you again that this is just an example off the top of my head.

Comment: It is a really awesome system, I got how it works, but there is one problem - I also need to analyze all the records, not only display them (for example, count all studies that are in Phase 3). And as far as I can see, this system just takes the data and puts it into HTML.
Plus, it reads all of them at the same time, not in chunks, like what I'm loooking for.

Comment: In regards to analysis, you can easily count all elements of a specific type. See the edit to my original post. As to your second point, I'm not sure what you mean. But XSL is extremely powerful. If you want to clarify what you mean I can probably figure out a way to accomplish the task.

Comment: okay as I mentioned in the first post, the file we're parsing is an "index" file (it contains bare search results and url to each of the studies). In order to get "Phase" you need to use the "url" part that leads to the full information about the study. Ex: [link](http://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT02027896?displayxml=true) . So, XLS is "take the data -> give me the template -> parse all data", what I need is "give me the data -> get the full data from url -> parse That full data individually". You know what I mean?